# Sort a data in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I have the next code:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState([
    { name: "Edward", value: 21 },
    { name: "Sharpe", value: 37 },
    { name: "And", value: 45 },
    { name: "The", value: -12 },
    { name: "Magnetic" },
    { name: "Zeros", value: 37 }
  ]);

  const sorting = () => {
    const a = state.sort(function (a, b) {
      if (a.name > b.name) {
        return 1;
      }
      if (a.name < b.name) {
        return -1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
    setState(a);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>data</th>
        </tr>
        {state.map((i) => {
          return (
            <tr key={i.name}>
              <td>{i.name}</td>
              <td>{i.value}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </table>
      <button onClick={sorting}>sort</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Clicking on the button i want to trigger the next function:

```js
 const sorting = () => {
    const a = state.sort(function (a, b) {
      if (a.name > b.name) {
        return 1;
      }
      if (a.name < b.name) {
        return -1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
    setState(a);
  };
```

Which should sort the data from table, but it does not happens.
Question:  Why my function does not work? ow to solve the issue that i described above? Note: when i will click on the button the data from table should change the order.

Comment: do you want to sort the list based on the alphabetical order of name or on the basis of value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before sorting convert the name to either uppercase or lowercase. After that, you can easily sort it with the help of `localeCompare()`:

```js
let data = [
  { name: "Edward", value: 21 },
  { name: "Sharpe", value: 37 },
  { name: "And", value: 45 },
  { name: "The", value: -12 },
  { name: "Magnetic" },
  { name: "Zeros", value: 37 },
];

data.sort((a, b) => a.name.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.name.toLowerCase()));

console.log(data);
```

Full react app:

[image]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState([
    { name: "Edward", value: 21 },
    { name: "Sharpe", value: 37 },
    { name: "And", value: 45 },
    { name: "The", value: -12 },
    { name: "Magnetic" },
    { name: "Zeros", value: 37 }
  ]);

  const sorting = () => {
    const data = [...state];
    data.sort((a, b) =>
      a.name.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.name.toLowerCase())
    );
    console.log(data);
    setState(data);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>data</th>
        </tr>
        {state.map(i => {
          return (
            <tr key={i.name}>
              <td>{i.name}</td>
              <td>{i.value}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </table>
      <button onClick={sorting}>sort</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can play with the working example here: [Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/namesortstackoverflow?file=src/App.js)